# No Sound after mounting /home

Tags: sound, mount, home-directory

There is no sound after mounting /home from another HDD (ntfs). The sound indicator is also vanished, so are the drivers (sytem settings -> sound)

The sound indicator is only shown before log in. After log in the indicator is gone. I have tried so many things and searched Google for more then a week now, installed Ubuntu  3 times...

Pls help, I don't want to go back to windows

If you need more info let me know

Comment: For Ubuntu to work properly, it probably needs to be another format to NTFS.

Comment: i was not hoping to hear that because of the amount of data in my home folder. But ill try to use a different format. Should I format to ext3 or ext4?

Comment: ect4 is better than ext3 *(I think)*. if you want to read it from a Windows machine, you can use [Ext2Fsd](http://www.ext2fsd.com/), which supports ext2 and ext3, and might support ext4. If you want to format it, [GParted](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/saucy/gparted/) works nicely off of Ubuntu, or a Live Disk, but as that is a `/home` partition`, you will need to place `/home` elsewhere, otherwise you won't be able to login.

Comment: I will back up my /home folder and format the HDD to ext4. Ill let you know if this solved the problem. Thnx for your help and info.

Comment: Don't format it using a user with a home folder in that `/home`, it might crash...

Comment: Saw your comment to late...I reinstalled Ubuntu and formatted (back-upped first) the other HDD to etx4, mounted /home again..... and after log in there was still sound!!! :D Thank you for your help!

Comment: You welcome! Glad you got it sorted :-) - I have done a vague answer so you can close this question as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try another format for `/home` than NTFS. It probably does not support the config files used by Linux, or messes them up or something.

Try formatting it to `ext4`. This is the best filesystem to run Linux off, and can probably be read from in Windows using [Ext2Fsd](http://www.ext2fsd.com/), which supports ext2 and ext3, and might support ext4.

If you want to format it, [GParted](http://gparted.org/) works nicely off a Live Disk - as this a `/home` partition, you will have to do this off a Live Disk or another machine, as you can't login with a user that needs that `/home` partition..

Another method would be to backup `/home`, and reinstall, formatting the `/home` partition to ext4.